# SOAP::Lite (WSDL) Response not correct deserialized (References)

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, wsdl

i have a problem with a SOAP-Response an i hope someone can help me.

I think something went wrong, when the SOAP-Response is deserialized by the SOAP::Lite Module. In the SOAP-Response are some "normal" Nodes and referenced Nodes. But non of it where correct deserialized.

**SOAP-Response:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:SOAP_GetFirmenlisteResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.4d.com/namespace/default">
    <ERRORNUM xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ERRORNUM>
    <ERRORTEXT xsi:type="xsd:string">
</ERRORTEXT>
    <LISTE_KDLF_NR_ALS_IDS href="#ref-1"/>  <LISTE_SUCHNAMEN href="#ref-2"/>    <LISTE_LFD_NR href="#ref-3"/>   <LISTE_TIMESTAMP_GEAENDERT href="#ref-4"/>  <LISTE_TIMESTAMP_ERZEUGT href="#ref-5"/>
</ns1:SOAP_GetFirmenlisteResponse>
<SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-1" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
<item1>19288</item1>
<item2>19289</item2>
<item3>60107</item3>
<item4>71897</item4>
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
<SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-2" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
<item1>Blabla1</item1>
<item2>Blabla2</item2>
<item3>Bla München</item3>
<item4>Blaürm BÄR</item4>
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
<SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-3" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:int[4]">
<item1>-8423</item1>
<item2>-8426</item2>
<item3>-8425</item3>
<item4>-8428</item4>
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
<SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-4" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
<item1>2015-11-23T09:32:23</item1>
<item2>2015-11-26T14:55:52</item2>
<item3>2015-11-26T08:07:26</item3>
<item4>2015-11-27T09:26:25</item4>
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
<SOAP-ENC:Array id="ref-5" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
<item1>2015-11-23T09:30:54</item1>
<item2>2015-11-26T14:52:06</item2>
<item3>2015-11-25T10:33:27</item3>
<item4>2015-11-27T09:24:05</item4>
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Dump of Result Hash:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ARRAY(0x2c16e08)' => undef,
          '0' => '',
          'ARRAY(0x2f42168)' => [
                                  'Blabla1',
                                  'Blabla2',
                                  "Bla M\x{fc}nchen",
                                  "Bla\x{fc}rm B\x{c4}R"
                                ],
          'ARRAY(0x2f39680)' => [
                                  '2015-11-23T09:32:23',
                                  '2015-11-26T14:55:52',
                                  '2015-11-26T08:07:26',
                                  '2015-11-27T09:26:25'
                                ]
        };
```

**Perl Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use SOAP::Lite +trace => [ transport => \&log_message ];

sub log_message {
   my ($in) = @_;
   my ($cont) = $in->content;
   $cont =~ s/></>\n</g;
   print "\n-------------------------------------------------\n";
   print $cont;
   print "\n-------------------------------------------------\n";
}

my $soap    = SOAP::Lite->service('http://192.168.0.13:8181/4dwsdl');

$soap->envprefix('SOAP-ENV');
$soap->encprefix('SOAP-ENC');
$soap->soapversion('1.1');


my %result  = $soap->SOAP_GetFirmenliste(
                                    '00',
                                    'SOAPTest',
                                    'soaptest',
                                    '0000-00-00',
                                    '2015-10-01'
                                    );

print Dumper(\%result);


exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem will be this:

```
my %result  = $soap->SOAP_GetFirmenliste(
```

Because the result of your `print` suggests that the first element returned by this is an array ref (that's being converted to a string).

I'm afraid I can't tell directly what it'll be returning, by I would suggest trying:

```
my $result = $soap -> SOAP_GetFirmenliste(
```

And then `print Dumper $result`

This should show you exactly what sort of data structure you are getting - it won't be a hash.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I changed the code as you suggest, but now i get only a `$VAR1 = '0';`. I think the return of `my $result = $soap -> SOAP_GetFirmenliste(...`  should be a SOAP::SOM Object. But however it is not.